# No response shown when using master-slave

Tags: jmeter

I have a script which sends a REST request. When I execute this request from the master with the JMeter GUI, the request is sent successfully and I see the response in the Results Tree Viewer.

When I do the same, but then using a JMeter slave to send the request, the request is still being sent successfully, but the response window of the Results Tree Viewer on the master is white, no response shown.

The slave has a successful connection with the application, because when I sent the request from the JMeter GUI from the slave machine, the response is correctly shown in the Results Tree Viewer.

So it seems to have to do something with the communication from the JMeter slave to the JMeter master is my assumption. What can be the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the below setting in your Master Jmeter

> mode=Standard

This will enable the response from Slave machines to be visible in "*View Results Tree*" Listener.
restart your Jmeter Master after changing/saving the settings.

Comment: Thanks! Will try this coming Monday when I am at the client!